# Why Do the Fingers in Mechanical Pencils Fly Out?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, product-engineering, forces

In this video(https://www.kidzsearch.com/kidztube/watch.php?vid=65fbcb9ca), at timestamp 0:27, it says that in mechanical pencils, the fingers have a taper in them that results in them flying out horizontally, unclamping the graphite.
I am confused about why this happens. Could someone please explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plastic fingers are moulded in the open position. During assembly and operation they are compressed.

[image]

I imagine that the fingers are moulded so that with the ring in the position shown they are in pre-tension. i.e., They are not fully open so that they still have some opening force in reserve.